# How to build/install usbip?

Tags: usb

I have installed the latest version of Raspbian and `uname -a` gives the following:

```
Linux mypi 3.6.11+ #541 PREEMPT Sat Sep 7 19:46:21 BST 2013 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

And I have used [these](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=8858&f=13) instruction by secretagent.

But when I try `modprobe usbip-host` the Pi hangs and must be rebooted.

Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: Did you look in the logs?

Comment: Yes, not a word!

Comment: I will try to run the modprobe directly at the shell. It may give me some more info. Currently I am accessing the Pi vi ssh.

Comment: Run the command at the console. There are some info, but I have not had the time to investigate futher.

Comment: Have you solved this issue yet? If so, could you please create a self-answer and mark it as such. We are trying to get the Q:A ratio up and that would help us a ton. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is important to make sure that the version of the kernel you are using and the modules you are compiling are matching. There are no safety nets in place; it will usually just crash if they don't line up.

It might be a good precaution to use the exact same kernel source used to compile the module to compile a new kernel image and replace the existing, though the wait is about 10 hours for build to finish on the rPI and takes >3GB. Offsite build might be the better way to go but I've never tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suspect there's an unfortunate interaction occurring between the less than stellar USB stack of the Pi and the software. You may need to wait a few kernel versions for the software to get better and then try again.